# Launch fails after meteor build

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor

I am creating a build from meteor source in a docker container.

It worked well so far (since last creation 1 or 2 weeks ago) but today an exception raises !

```
at /home/meteor/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:462:11
at /home/meteor/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:423:13
at Function.run (/home/meteor/build/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
at /home/meteor/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:464:5
at Function.time (/home/meteor/build/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:309:28)
TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function
at insert (packages/mongo/collection.js:435:12)
at packages/autoupdate.js:189:3
at updateVersions (packages/autoupdate.js:125:20)
throw(ex);
/home/meteor/build/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
```

NB : log may be not ordered as I use ELK stack to handle it

What happened ? And what to do to solve it ?

FYI: the application works well locally (not builded)

Comment: What commands are you running to build the app? What docker container are you using, or if you are building your own container, can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: @bluescores here -> https://github.com/Antoine-O/docker-meteor-src/blob/master/Dockerfile .

Comment: in fact node 6 is deployed by default in alpine. I think have to modify (A LOT) my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node 6 is currently default in alpine, that was the issue. I switch to node image which is safer (but bigger).